# Does 'for' here mean despite? and Does 'lightness' here mean light-minded?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She had gathered these things from time to time when she had gone to the Sunday-school with the children, and had laid them up in her memory more carefully than she had done with those other words and phrases; and she had studied them deeply, for her good and ours. One may see by this that she had a wise and thoughtful head, **for** all there was so much **lightness** and vanity in it. (Mark Twain, *A Dog's Tale*)

Does *for* here mean despite? and Does *lightness* here mean 'light-minded'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"for all" can be used synonymously with *despite*. e.g.:

> For all his boasting, he's really not all that talented

It's kind of an old phrasing of the expression, but I agree with your parsing. And I think [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lightness) is more like the intended usage of *lightness*:

> lack of seriousness and stability of character often accompanied by casual heedlessness

Comment: Yes, good example for _for all_. 'All' might be retained (Despite all his boasting, he hasn't really got much talent). In OP, _for all (there was . . .)_ has to be replaced by _despite the fact that (there was . . .)_ or the equivalent.